# Generic Quicksort

Tags: c, sorting, qsort

Below are the code snippets of generic qsort on C.

What do I write in the fourth parameter of the genmyqsort when it's called in the recursion?

```
int compnode(node *a, node *b){
   return(strcmp(a->name,b->name));
}

void genmyqsort(void *a, int n, int size, int (*fcmp)(const void*,const void*)){
  int pivot;

  if(n>1){
    pivot=partition(a,n,size);
    genmyqsort(a*size, pivot,size);
    genmyqsort(a+(pivot+1)*size,n-pivot-1,size);
  }
}
```

call of Qsort in main.

```
genmyqsort(b,n,sizeof(node),(int(*)(const void*, const void*)) compnode);
```

Comment: I think you only need to pass the compare function pointer to the partition function.

Comment: What's a node? Are you getting a compile error? You don't appear to be using fcmp anywhere

Comment: passed (int(*)(const void*, const void*)) compnode as the fourth parametere. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the same comparator as you got from the caller (`fcmp`):

```
genmyqsort(a*size, pivot, size, fcmp);
genmyqsort(a+(pivot+1)*size, n-pivot-1, size, fcmp);
```

This will ensure that all instances of `genmyqsort()` in the call tree will compare array elements in exactly the same way.